# jquery overscroll + draggable items

Tags: jquery, scroll, draggable

I have a part of html code:

```
<div class="stories">
    <div class="story">                         
        <div class="..">
            <img alt="" class="..">
        </div>
        <div class="dragger"></div> 
    <div>

    <div class="story">
        ...
        <div class="dragger"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

"dragger" is an element allows you to drag "story" block on a page with this jquery code:

```
$('.dragger').mousedown(function(e){
    $(this).parent().draggable({
        disabled: false, opacity: 0.5, zIndex: 2700, revert: true,
        stop: function() { $(this).draggable({ disabled: true }) }
})
```

It works very good until I put this "story" element into an overscroll area. I would like to make scrolling when I manage 'click and drag' anywhere besides small area which is a "dragger". So eg. when I mousedown on a story I want to scroll. I tried to use 'cancelOn' parameter with a ".dragger" but it doesn't work as I wish - scrolling is being blocked but (and I don't know why) "story" item is also not able to be dragged then over the page.

Here is a code of 'overscroll'

```
$(".scheduled").overscroll({
    direction: 'horizontal',
    wheelDirection: 'horizontal',
    wheelDelta: 80,
    cancelOn: ".dragger"
});
```

".scheduled" is an "upper" div in which stories are put. Do you have some ideas?

Regards,
galsan

Answer (score 4):

the event may not be bubbling up when you use `cancelOn`, and that could be breaking draggable. Try disabling overscroll temporarily (using `removeOverscroll`) when the element you wish to drag is clicked. Once dragging is done, you can re-enable the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried this trick with disable/enable overscroll before but after disable default (gray windows-like) scrollbars show up so I rejected this solution. But ok, I`ll try this once more with some modifications. Thx

Comment: Did you figure out how to make this work? I'm looking for a solution to a similar problem.